# Cantidad de digitos al usar printf

Tags: c, printf

Mi consulta es bastante sencilla, pero no puedo encontrar la respuesta. 
Necesito especificar la cantidad de digitos a imprimirse cuando uso printf con un entero.

Especificamente quiero imprimir siempre 5 digitos, independientemente que mi numero entero tenga una cantidad mayor o menor a 5.

Por ejemplo si tengo el número 123456, quiero que se vea 12345.
Ahora si tengo el numero 123, quiero que se vea 12300. (No necesito autocompletar con ceros al principio, sino al final)

Probé haciendo lo siguiente:

```
printf("%05i",numero); // Pero autocompleta con ceros al principio
```

También probé:

```
printf("%5i",numero); // Pero ignora completamente ese 5 e imprime la cantidad total de digitos
```

Hay algun otro argumento de printf que resuelva esto? O debo crear una función propia?

Gracias!

Comment: No se puede hacer directamente lo que dices, especificar número de digitos son para números de punto flotante

Comment: tendrías que hacer una función que complete con ceros o elimine elementos

Comment: Tendrias que hacer una funcion antes del print, que te acorte el entero a un total de 5 digitos , y despues recien mostrarlo .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si quieres trabajar con enteros directamente puedes hacer una simple división:

```
numero = 123456;
printf("%i", numero/10); // Imprime 12345
```

Y bueno, para añadir dígitos bastaría con multiplicar por 10:

```
numero = 123;
printf("%i", numero*100); // Imprime 12300
```

También se puede hacer de forma genérica:

```
int rectificarDigitos(int numero, int maxDigitos)
{
  int digitos = log10(numero) + 1;
  while( digitos > maxDigitos )
  {
    numero /= 10;
    digitos--;
  }

  while( digitos < maxDigitos )
  {
    numero *= 10;
    digitos++;
  }

  return numero; 
}

int main()
{
  int numero = rectificarDigitos(123456,5);
  printf("%i\n", numero);

  numero = rectificarDigitos(123,5);
  printf("%i\n", numero);
}
```

También podrías convertir el número en cadena de texto e ignorar los dígitos que no te interesan:

```
int numero = 123456;
char strNumero[10];
sprintf(strNumero,"%d",numero);
strNumero[5] = 0;
printf("%s",strNumero);
```

Y, para rematar, podemos hacer uso de ciertas características de `printf`:

```
void printNumero(int numero, int size)
{
  int digitos = log10(numero)+1;

  if( digitos < size )
  {
    printf("%d%0*d\n", numero, size-digitos, 0);
    //                  (1)       (2)       (3)
    // 1: "%d" -> numero a imprimir
    // 2: "%0*d" -> cantidad de que se repetira el numero al que precede
    // 3: "%0*d" -> numero a imprimir
  }
  else
  {
    if( digitos > size )
    {
      int div = pow(10,digitos-size);
      numero /= div;
    }

    printf("%d\n", numero);
  }
}

int main()
{
  printNumero(123456,5);
  printNumero(123,5);
}
```

---

**EDITO:**

Dado que has aclarado en tu respuesta que usas un microcontrolador, te propongo una posible mejora de tu función:

```
uint32_t integer_right_padding(uint32_t number, uint8_t desired_digits)
{
  uint8_t original_digits=0;

  for(uint32_t number_backup=number; number_backup != 0; original_digits++ )
  {
    number_backup/=10;
  }

  for( ; original_digits > desired_digits; original_digits-- )
    number /= 10;

  for( ; original_digits < desired_digits; original_digits++ )
    number *= 10;

  return number;
}
```

¿En qué mejora?

- El ámbito de las variables se reduce (cualquier compilador compatible con C99 debería admitir como válido declarar variables en un `for`)
- Te ahorras una comparación en cada iteración para ajustar el número de dígitos.
- El bucle para ajustar el número de dígitos hace menos operaciones.

La función se podría optimizar aún más, pero si no es imprescindible yo optaría por dejarla así ya que el código empezaría a ser más feo.

Comment: En la parte que indicas `char strNumero[10];
sprintf(strNumero,"%d",numero);` te falta rellenar `strNumero` con caracteres `'0'` ¿no?.

Comment: Sí, era por ir subiendo la pregunta... la estoy editando

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y tu respuesta. Es perfectamente válida, pero como me encuentro programando en un microcontrolador, me conviene utilizar la función que cree yo así no tengo que incluir las librerías string ni math y puedo optimizar el uso de la memoria. Pero nuevamente muchas gracias

Comment: @cventu, he editado la respuesta en base a lo que comentas del micro, por si te interesa

Comment: Gracias, me interesa la forma en que reduciste el número de operaciones e iteraciones. No tanto la idea de declarar variables dentro del for, por más que el compilador lo permita no es una muy buena práctica. Gracias!!

Comment: @cventu Perdona que te corrija, pero que las variables han de tener una vida lo más corta posible no es algo que defineda yo sino cualquiera con suficientes años de experiencia programando. Y más en C que su creación es gratuita

Comment: Claro, pero en este caso particular al ser el for el único bucle dentro de la función, el uso del stack es exactamente el mismo si se coloca la variable al comienzo de la función o al comienzo del for. Y en ese caso, es recomendable colocarlo al comienzo de la función. Pero si, es cierto lo que dices, cuando hay posibilidad de optimizar el uso del stack es recomendable que el scope de las variables sea el más corto posible.

Comment: @cventu no se, no veo ninguna ventaja declarar la variable al inicio de la función, a diferencia de declararla dentro del `for`. Si está dentro del `for` y necesitas realizar nuevas optimizaciones el código de la función crecerá y se volverá más complejo... pero esa variable no te molestará porque fuera del `for` no existirá. Es como una mesa de trabajo... ¿prefieres tenerlo todo desparramado aunque no lo uses en ese momento o sacar únicamente las herramientas que necesitas en cada momento?

Comment: Bueno creo que ya hemos perdido un poco el foco de la pregunta. Por suerte el problema inicial está resuelto, el resto son detalles. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo!

Comment: Un placer, sería interesante discutir el tema... Quizás en meta

Answer (score 3):

Imprime el número en un búfer de caracteres rellanado con ceros y pon el caracter de finalización de cadena siempre en la posición 6 del búfer:

```
char buffer[11] = {'0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 0};
int escrito = snprintf(buffer, 10, "%d", numero);
buffer[escrito] = '0';
buffer[5] = 0;
printf("%s\n", buffer);
```

El `buffer` del ejemplo anterior tiene 11 caracteres ya que 10 son los dígitos máximos que puede tener un entero (`int`)<sup>*</sup>, el 11º caracter del búffer es el caracter de finalización de cadena (fíjate que no tiene comillas).

Imprimimos el número en el búfer, la función `snprintf` devuelve la cantidad de caracteres escritos, así que en la última posición escrita volvemos a poner el caracter `'0'` (ya que `snprintf` habrá escrito el caracter finalizador de cadena).

Finalmente, en la posición 6 (lugar en que queremos truncar siempre el número) ponemos el caracter de finalización de cadena.

Por ejemplo, supongamos que queremos mostrar los números 42 y 101010:

```
 buffer         | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10|
snprintf 42     |'4'|'2'| 0 |'0'|'0'|'0'|'0'|'0'|'0'|'0'| 0 |
snprintf 101010 |'1'|'0'|'1'|'0'|'1'|'0'| 0 |'0'|'0'|'0'| 0 |
```

Al imprimir 42, la posición 2 del búfer se marca como final de cadena (con `0`), sucede lo mismo con la posición 6 al imprimir 101010. Dado que en el primer caso hemos escrito 2 caracteres y en el segundo 6, la instrucción `buffer[escrito] = '0'` nos deja el búfer así:

```
buffer | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10|
42     |'4'|'2'|'0'|'0'|'0'|'0'|'0'|'0'|'0'|'0'| 0 |
101010 |'1'|'0'|'1'|'0'|'1'|'0'|'0'|'0'|'0'|'0'| 0 |
```

Si mostráramos el número en ese momento veríamos `4200000000` y `1010100000` respectivamente, así que usamos la instrucción `buffer[5] = 0;` que nos deja así el búfer:

```
buffer | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10|
42     |'4'|'2'|'0'|'0'|'0'| 0 |'0'|'0'|'0'|'0'| 0 |
101010 |'1'|'0'|'1'|'0'|'1'| 0 |'0'|'0'|'0'|'0'| 0 |
```

Por lo que mostrando el número en ese momento veríamos `42000` y `10101` respectivamente.

---

<sup>*</sup>En arquitecturas de 32 bits, el número máximo de un entero es (2<sup>32</sup>/2) - 1 = 2.147.483.648

Comment: Da gusto cuando hay respuestas diferentes a elegir. Esto en C/C++ ultimamente es complicado de encontrar

Comment: @eferion te voy a dar una colleja... ¡C/C++ no existe! >:(

Comment: Lo se, yo hablo de C y de C++

Comment: ¡Pues escribe "C y C++"! Estoy en contra del uso del término "C/C++". :P

Comment: Muchas gracias! Muy interesante dar implementación

Answer (score 2):

No encontré ningun argumento de printf para hacer lo que estaba buscando asi que creé una función que se ocupa de ello. Se las comparto por si les interesa o la necesitan en el futuro.

```
uint32_t integer_right_padding(uint32_t number, uint8_t desired_digits)
{
    uint8_t original_digits=0;
    uint32_t number_backup=number;
    uint8_t indexer=0;

    while ( number_backup >= 10)
    {
         number_backup/=10;
         original_digits++;
    }
    original_digits++;

    for (indexer=0 ; (indexer < (abs(desired_digits-original_digits))) ;     indexer++)
    {
        if (original_digits < desired_digits)
        {
            number*=10;
        }
        else
        {
            number/=10;
        }
    }

    return number;
}
```

La función recibe dos argumentos, el primero es el número que se quiere autocompletar o recortar y el segundo es la cantidad de digitos que se desean.

Ejemplos:

```
integer_right_padding(123, 5); // Devuelve 12300
integer_right_padding(123456, 2); // Devuelve 12
```

y asi sucesivamente... Espero que les sirva!